# Cursor leaves window when typing (ncurses)

Tags: c, linux, terminal, ncurses

I am using ncurses to make a simple TUI for my application.
I got the basics of creating and printing to a window, but I have problems with input.

When I finish writing, the cursor is positioned at the end of the string I wrote
[image]

But when I start typing, cursor moves to the top-left corner of terminal window.

[image]

How can I keep it in place while typing?

Here's my code:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

WINDOW *win;
int startx, starty, width, height;
int cport;


WINDOW *makewin(int h, int w, int y, int x)
{
    WINDOW *lwin;

    lwin = newwin(h, w, y, x);
    box(lwin, 0 , 0);
    wrefresh(lwin);

    return lwin;
}

void dewin(WINDOW *lwin)
{
    wborder(lwin, ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ');
    wrefresh(lwin);
    delwin(lwin);
}

void getPort(){
    win = makewin(height, width, starty, startx);
    wbkgd(win, COLOR_PAIR(1));
    mvwprintw(win, 0, 8, "Port Settings");
    mvwprintw(win, 2, 4, "Set port server should");
    mvwprintw(win, 3, 4, "listen to: ");
    wrefresh(win);

    scanw("%d", &cport);
}

int main()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);


        start_color();

        init_pair(1,COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);
        init_pair(2,COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLUE);
        bkgd(COLOR_PAIR(2));
        refresh();

        height = 6;
        width = 30;
        starty = (LINES - height) / 2;
        startx = (COLS - width) / 2;

        getPort();


    getch();

    dewin(win);
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't even thought, that windows also have a dedicated function for reading, as it happens with printing. Using **wscanw** fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using `scanw(...)` function which ultimately acts like `wscanw(stdscr, ...)` which gets input from `stdscr`. Use `wscanw` function to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[`scanw`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_scanw.3x.html) (and `wscanw`) ultimately call [`wgetch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters), which refreshes the window given as its parameter:

> If the window is not a pad, and it has been moved or modified since the last call to  [`wrefresh`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_refresh.3x.html#h3-refresh_wrefresh),  `wrefresh`  will  be
>   called before another character is read.

That is, any pending changes (including the erasure due to `initscr`) for `stdscr` would be applied by a plain `scanw`.  The cursor will be left at the current position in the  window where the program asks for input.